# Running jar file from php gives different output as from the terminal

Tags: php

I have a jar file that needs to access a credentials file from (/home/user) location.

Now while running from the terminal, it works properly. However, when I execute

```
exec("java -jar Main.jar");
```

from php, it gives me an error, asking me to check if my file is at the location, and is formatted (catch was activated after it couldn't get the credentials).
Now I assumed this was a permissions issue, and so I used

```
is_readable("/home/user/credentials")
```

It said that the file was readable. So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the jar file resides in the same location of php file which you are trying to read and also the java environmental variable is set properly to run java from anywhere.

Comment: It is in the same location. The jar file is running, but behaves unexpectedly.